# Subtract minimum of a numpy array containing list with every element of that array

Tags: python, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

image containing the array B
[image: image containing the array B]

different properties of B and what i am trying to do
[image: different properties of B and what i am trying to do]

Please see the images to look for details.

I want to perform B - np.min(B)

Comment: Please do NOT include code screenshots into your question. Include the actual code and output.

Comment: Please add a simplified example. Do you expect people to create the example?

Comment: Anyway have you tried reshape function?

Comment: Why to use reshape function? Actually, I am new to StackOverflow. I would keep this in mind next time. I want to subtract min value in B with every element of B. But you can see there is an error because of the type of B and it's element. How can i do it?

Comment: The error is right there: you can't do an operation on variables of different data types. Since this is a mathematical operation, have you tried B.astype(float) - np.min(B)?
Since you haven't provided any examples, we can't test to see if this works or not. Please read the guidelines before asking a question.

Comment: The error is right there: you can't do an operation on variables of different data types. Since this is a mathematical operation, have you tried B.astype(float) - np.min(B)?

Comment: No problem. It was solved. I just had to convert each element of B to an array using np.asaraay(B[i,j]). After then I can subtract it directly from np.min(B). Thank you for your insight though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to subtract the min value of each from the corresponding row? If it is the case, you can use the code below:

```
B-np.min(B, axis=0).reshape(-1, 1)
```